# How to clean a file

Tags: r

I have a disorganised data like this. But this is only a small sample, please assume I have multiple columns, perhaps 100

```
df<-read.table (text=" ID   Name    Temp    Colour  time1   time1_val   time2   time2_val   time3   time3_val

'NA'    'NA'    'NA'    'NA'    'R' 'NA'    'P' 'NA'    'G' 'NA'
'NA'    'NA'    'NA'    'NA'    '12'    'NA'    '10'    'NA'    '9' 'NA'
1   'Rose'  '40'    'Yellow'    'R' '12'    'C' '8' 'A' 26
2   'Smith' '60'    'Blue'  'B' '13'    'M' '4' 'B' '33'
b   'Ong'   'C' 'Red'   'D' '14'    'N' '3' 'C' '2'


", header=TRUE)
```

I want to delete all columns but keep time 1,2, 3 vals here is the intended outcome:

```
   time1_val    time2_val   time3_val
    12               8           26
    13               4           33
    14               3           2
```

Comment: May you run `dput(data)` with `data` is the first 10 rows of your original data.

Comment: Can you show your expected result for the data you shared please. Your data headers has 15 distinct names hence 15 columns (`ID  Name    Temp    Colour  time1   time1 val   time 2  time2 val   time 3  time4 val`) but maybe some of these should be, for example, `time3` or `time1_val` etc

Comment: I have updated the question. the outcome is the second table. there a space between  time and val

Comment: @user330; I get what you want but it would be good to show the logic of how the data are meant to align under the column headers. Although from your expected outcome perhaps it is enough to extract the 6, 8, and 10th terms? e.g. using your data in the question `dat = read.table(...,  header=FALSE, skip=2)` then grab the relevant column??

Comment: I want to delete all columns and Missings (NA) and I want to get three columns as I have shown. The columns are time 1 val, time2 val and time 3 val. I have failed to create dput(), but I tried my best

Comment: @user330 Is it possible for you to read with `readLines` if the columns are not in order.  This may require some `dput` to understand the correct structure

Comment: I am trying to creat it. I understand it

Comment: I have updated  please see if this does work for you, thank you

Comment: I guess `df %>% select(matches('^time\\d+_val$')) %>% na.omit` should work based on the example showed

Comment: Can you elaborate on logic of going from input to output? I am not sure how 5 rows get's reduced to 3 rows and 10 columns to 3 columns?

Comment: The logic is that I want to remove all columns and only keep the columns that have numbers only, after skipping 2 rows. I have updated the outcome

Comment: Please include that in your original post, this is important information to get the output.

Comment: Why isn't `ID` and `Temp` column not selected? They also have numbers only.

Comment: I have updated  it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` this should give you the desired results:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  dplyr::select(dplyr::ends_with("_val")) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(time1_val))
```

Comment: I guess, the function `select` is masked by another package. I updated the code.

Comment: Can you please post sample data using `dput()`?

Comment: I have updated  so, if I want to use it for more columns, say time 1, time2... can you help?

Comment: I updated the code. It gives me the exact outcome you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
col_names <- names(df)   
# apply regex
col_names <- col_names[grep('^time\\d+$', names(df))]
df <- df[,col_names]
```

The data frame will be updated with only columns that were selected.

Comment: If I have, say 50 times, time1, time2 ,... Can we do better?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get the outcome.